# Saving single value which is checked in checkbox in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I have a problem with checkbox. When I click the update button, it will change all the values of the column into 1 while I want only the checked one to become 1.
Here is my form:

```
<form action="{{ route('restaurant.saveCheckUpdatedItems') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
<td><input type="checkbox" id="checked" name="checked[]" value=""></td>
```

Controller:

```
    $data = $request->input('checked');
    $items = ItemReservationItem::whereIn('restaurant_id', $restaurantIds)->get();
    for($i=0; $i < $items->count(); $i++){
         if(empty($data)) {
            $items[$i]->done_check = 0;
         }
         else {
            $items[$i]->done_check = 1;
         }
         $items[$i]->save();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

I only want the checked rows is 1, but it changes all the table into 1.

Comment: if(empty($data)) { this will always be true because you did not define $data. Perhas you mean empty($items[$i]) ?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond Sorry I forgot putting it into the question. Here is my definition for $data: $data = $request->input('checked');

Comment: could you print out your input 'checked'? is it an array of item id?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond No, it is not an array of item_id

Comment: then how do you know which checkboxes are being checked?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond if I check $request->get('checked');, I think the checkbox is not checked. How to make it be checked?

Comment: you should include the key that you'll know which id needs updating. im guessing each row is under some loop so: `checked[{{ $restaurant->id }}]` or something, then you'll get the keys you need. then a simple where in update is all you need